# How to show fid with slideshow image

Tags: 7, media, views, files

I have very specific requirement. I want to show images in slideshow.
I have created content type **"User Slideshow Snaps"** and two fields

- Slideshow Snaps
- Node Id

I want to show slieshow of images in field **Slideshow Snaps** which belongs to Node Id passed in URL.

The slideshow is working perfectly and I have used Modules **Views Slideshow** & **Views Slideshow: Cycle** for this.

Now I want to link Slideshow to external page which will pass FID of current image in slideshow like this:-

[image]

But I am facing problem in passing fid of clicked image in slideshow.
This configuration is always passing FID of first image in slideshow even if user clicked on 8th image in slideshow.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What Node ID field is going to do? You want to link the slide show image to it's content?

Comment: All slideshow images belongs to one particular node ID. Ex. Node ID 1 contain 2 images. So when user visits node 1 in the website then the view will display all the image related to node 1 in slideshow. I hope it clears your query.

Comment: So it differs from the image node , yes?

Comment: Yes..It differs from image node.

Answer (score 1):

You may use views template files. If your view name is `gallery` and it's machine name is `block_0` then in your theme folder create a file and name it `views-view-fields--gallery--block-0.tpl.php`.

There are two fields in the content type, an image with the machine name `field_image` and a text that is address of some where else with the machine name `field_link`.

In the `views-view-fields--gallery--block-0.tpl.php` file the following variables are available

```
1. $fields['field_image']->content;
2. $fields['field_link']->content;
```

To create a slideshow like this

[image]

with a string on it you can easily use html tags and css absolute positions to set the string on the image. Anyway you can display it in any way you want. Don't forget to clear the cache.

Comment: I will surely try this. +1 for giving me a different direction to think.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try creating view for files entities (not for nodes).
2. Add relationship to parent node
3. Add contextual filter for node id using "relationship to parent node"

Comment: I have just tried it. I have created view of file entity and try to reproduce the same with the help of relationship to parent node.But it shows slideshow of images in multiple row. So if any slideshow contain 8 images then this result into 8 rows of slideshow. This is quite natural because we are joining based on FID which is unique for 8 rows. If I am doing anything wrong then please let me know.